# Sorting a list with negative numbers as strings produces unexpected result

Tags: python, list, sorting

I made a program to calculate the second largest number from a list. Input is a string that is sliced into a list. Here's the code

```
score1 = input()
score = score1.split()
score.sort()
maximum = max(score)
count = score.count(maximum)
for i in range(0,count):
    score.pop()
print(max(score))
```

And it is working fine for positive numbers but if the list contains a negative number my program fails to produce the correct answer.

> **For Input**  `-7 -7 -7 -7 -6`

> **Output is** `-6` instead of `-7`

Any way to improve it?

Comment: Your numbers are evaluated as strings, not numbers. Hint: `list(map(int, score1.split()))`…

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `-7` in your example?

Comment: Very similar, maybe a duplicate? [Python sorting list with negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42430379/4518341)

Answer (score 7):

Since the input is a string, when you call `sort` and `max` they're working lexicographically, not numerically. You need to convert to integers first:

```
score = [int(item) for item in score1.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code does not work for negative numbers *(btw it also does not work for numbers with more than 1 digits as well*) is that you are not sorting numbers, you are sorting strings. `input()`'s return value is always a string since no implicit conversion takes place. Therefore, in order to get the result you want you have to cast them to some number form first.

```
score = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
score.sort()
```

after that you can do whatever you want with it.

Note that wrapping the list-comprehension in a `try-except` block would also be a good idea to avoid bad input.

Answer (score 1):

```
score1 = input()
score = score1.split()

#converting the list of strings into list of integers
score = [int(i) for i in score]

#removing duplicates
score = list(set(score))

#sorting the list
score.sort()

#printing the second largest number

print(score[-2])
```

Comment: Shorter: `score = sorted(set(score))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get your expected answer by doing this :

```
score = input().split()
li = []

for value in score:
    x = int(value) # converting to int
    li.append(x) # appending to empty list
final = set(li) # removing duplicates values
print(max(final)) # getting the maximum value
```

Hope that it will help you ..

Answer (score -2):

Try this maybe:

```
score1 = input()
score = score1.split()
score = sorted(set(map(int, score)))
second_max=score[-2]
```

Comment: why the `set` and `list` calls? 1) you don't need them and 2) using `set` removes the duplicates which might be a mistake in this case.

Comment: This goes too far in anticipating what the OP might want to do with the list. It's one thing to remove all occurrences of the maximum element; it's quite another to assume that all duplicates should be removed as well.

Comment: Well if i didn't misunderstand OP he want to get the second largest distinct number from his input right?